# adding a .pth voice model to tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

with the help of RVC, I made a voice model, when I try to add it to the code, I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\kostr\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\test.py", line 31, in
>
> voice_synthesis(text, model_path, config_path)
> File "C:\Users\kostr\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\test.py", line 10, in
> voice_synthesis
> model = tf.saved_model.load(model_path)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\kostr\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\load.py",
> line 900, in load
> result = load_partial(export_dir, None, tags, options)["root"]
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\kostr\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\load.py",
> line 1005, in load_partial
> loader_impl.parse_saved_model_with_debug_info(export_dir))
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\kostr\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\loader_impl.py",
> line 59, in parse_saved_model_with_debug_info
> saved_model = parse_saved_model(export_dir)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\kostr\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\loader_impl.py",
> line 119, in parse_saved_model
> raise IOError( OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: G_2333333.pth>>>{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}

here is the code itself:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import pyttsx3
import json



def voice_synthesis(text, model_path, config_path):
    model = tf.saved_model.load(model_path)

    with open(config_path, 'r') as f:
        config = json.load(f)

    engine = pyttsx3.init()
    engine.setProperty('rate', config['rate'])
    engine.setProperty('volume', config['volume'])
    engine.setProperty('voice', config['voice'])

    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()


model_path = 'G_2333333.pth'
config_path = 'venv/config.json'
text = 'Привет! Как дела?'
voice_synthesis(text, model_path, config_path)
```

I have already tried to transfer "G_2333333" to venv/lib/site-packages, but another error appears:

> Fatal Python error: init_import_site: Failed to import the site module
> Python runtime state: initialized Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 1176, in _find_and_load
> File "", line 1147, in
> _find_and_load_unlocked   File "", line 690, in _load_unlocked   File "", line
> 980, in exec_module   File "", line 616, in <module
> File "", line 599, in main   File "", line
> 531, in venv   File "", line 384, in addsitepackages
> File "", line 226, in addsitedir   File "",
> line 179, in addpackage   File
> "C:\Users\kostr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\encodings\cp1251.py",
> line 23, in decode
> return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position
> 1992: character maps to 
> tell me, is it possible to implement it at all, if so, how